# ANGULAR API AND LOCALSTORAGE

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have one task, where i need to search a movie from api through search bar. if the movie name is exist in localstorage then return from local storage otherwise return from the omdbapi.If the movie is found from the api then it should again store to the local storage. this task i need to do in angular.
[image]

Comment: Then what's the question? Anyway if you want to share your angular app, stackblitz.com is good to use

Comment: what issue you are facing in this

Comment: How to do this.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-id8zvx?file=src/app/app.component.html here is the code

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . You haven't provided enough informations.

Comment: According to the stackblitz code, you have not implemented much except the HTML page.  Therefore it is  difficult to answer your question to the point. The 'movieData'  must be an array of objects.  The searching should be done from that array but not using a single movie object  you might have stored in the localstorage.  You have to cache that movie array somewhere (localstorage or a separate service).   Please try to catch something from this article: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-persist-state-with-localstorage-in-angular-42a4a47ed123

Answer (score 0):

```
  let fetchval = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('movie_name'))
  if(fetchval){
    if exits 
  }else{
   // API call here from omdbapi
  }
```